# Gradle build - Resolve dependencies from downloaded archive

Tags: gradle, download, task, multi-project, external-dependencies

I'm fairly new to Gradle. I have a multi-project build that uses some dependencies currently packaged within the project (using repositories and flatDir), as they're not available in an artifactory.
I want to remove this local folder and download a couple of archives holding these dependencies, unpack them and proceed with the build as regular. I will use https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/de.undercouch.download for downloading, but I don't know how to this before any dependency resolution (and ideally, download if not already done). Currently, the build fails in the configuration phase as far as I can tell:

```
  `A problem occurred configuring project ':sub-project-A'.
  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sub-project-A:compileCopy'.
    Could not find :<some-dependency>:.
```

EDIT: Downloading the files works. Still struggling with unzipping the archives:

```
task unzipBirt(dependsOn: downloadPackages, type: Copy) {
    println 'Unpacking archiveA.zip'
    from zipTree("${projectDir}/lib/archiveA.zip")     
    include "ReportEngine/lib"
    into "${projectDir}/new_libs"
}
```

How do I make this run in the configuration phase ?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using copy to force the unzip in the configuration phase

```
copy {
     ..
     from zipTree(zipFile)
     into outputDir
     ..  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Project.files(Object...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#files-java.lang.Object...-) which states

> You can pass any of the following types to this method:
>
> ...
>
> A Task. Converted to the task's output files. The task is executed if the file collection is used as an input to another task.

So you can do:

```
task download(type: Download) {
    ... 
    into "$buildDir/download" // I'm guessing the config here
}
task unzip {
    dependsOn download
    inputs.dir "$buildDir/download"
    outputs.dir "$buildDir/unzip"
    doLast {
        // use project.copy here instead of Copy task to delay the zipTree(...)
        copy {
            from zipTree("$buildDir/download/archive.zip")
            into "$buildDir/unzip"
        }
    }
}
task dependency1 {
    dependsOn unzip
    outputs.file "$buildDir/unzip/dependency1.jar" 
}
task dependency2 {
    dependsOn unzip
    outputs.file "$buildDir/unzip/dependency2.jar" 
}
dependencies {
    compile files(dependency1)
    testCompile files(dependency2) 
}
```

Note: if there's lots of jars in the zip you can do

```
['dependency1', 'dependency2', ..., 'dependencyN'].each {
    tasks.create(it) {
        dependsOn unzip
        outputs.file "$buildDir/unzip/${it}.jar" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Managed to get the download working. Can't extract the files though, I think it's a build life cycle issue I don't full understand yet

Comment: Perhaps you are forcing the `Configuration` to [resolve()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#resolve--) in the configuration phase instead of the execution phase. If this is the case then the tasks don't have a chance to execute. See [Build Phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases)

Comment: I'm sure I do, I just don't really understand the trigger. In the sub project I have some local dependencies defined for a configuration like this:[name: '<some_dependency>']. Defining them this way forces the resolution in the configuration phase ?

Comment: Whoops, I think it was my original solution which had build lifecycle issues. Please see my updated solution